# Directory browsing without using a web.config on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying to set up directory browsing for a file share to which my IIS server (7.5 on Windows 2008) has read-only access. I have tried configuring directory browsing using the IIS Manager, and also by directly editing the `\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` file.

Despite my best efforts each time I attempt to view my virtual directory in IE I am met with a `HTTP Error 500.19 (Cannot read configuration file)` exception. It appears that IIS is attempting to locate a web.config file in the physical file share (which obviously doesn't exist).

Given that my file share will only ever be read-only, is there any way to configure directory browsing on my virtual directory without the requirement for a web.config file in the physical directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending considerable time on this I finally conceded to the `HTTP 500.19` error. Despite my best efforts to convince it otherwise, `IIS` insisted on the `web.config` being present in the file share.

I ended up writing my own file system wrapper which essentially produced the same output as the default directory browser, and then deployed it with a dedicated service account with read access.